# How to detect if video has just begun to play using Youtube API?

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api, youtube-iframe-api

I have a youtube player embed done with API as instructed in [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?csw=1#Loading_a_Video_Player). Player works fine, so far good. Next for analytics, I want to trigger an analytics event when the video has just started playing (like at clip 1 of video).

From [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?csw=1#onStateChange), I am able to read `YT.PlayerState.PLAYING === event.data` at onStateChange event. But this event is fired when user pauses and plays; skips to different clip and plays; video buffers and plays etc. I have to fire my analytics event ONLY when video just started to play at clip 1. Is there an event/way to check if video is playing from clip 1.

Note: I tried storing the previous states and then comparing. I dont feel it is a clean solution. Looking for a better way.

Comment: `onStateChange` if `event.data === 1` test for a variable that you have set.

Comment: No pls read, event.data === 1 is fired so many times within the video. I only want when played at clip 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var videoBegan = false;
if (!videoBegan){
    // Your code to fire after the video has began
}

if(YT.PlayerState.PLAYING === event.data){
    videoBegan = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the YouTube API, you can try updateTimerDisplay() to see if the video has started playing or use getCurentTime() to find how many seconds you are into the video.